# Return an IQueryable<dynamic> to filter in the parent method

Tags: c#, linq

For example, I have this code:

```
      IQueryable<MyModel> q = new List<MyModel>().AsQueryable(); // this is just an example, this is obviously not a list

      var query = from item in q select new { item.Property };

      var oneItem = query.FirstOrDefault(x => x.SomeProperty == somevalue);
      var allItems = query.ToArray();
```

Now in a bit more complex situation, I need to get `oneItem` and `allItems` in two different methods. So to follow DRY, i'd like to move my query to a private method and then in the consuming ones just call `this.GetQuery().FirstOrDefault()` or `.ToArray()` as required.

However, when I try to have the method as `IQueryable<dynamic>` I get the 'An expression tree may not contain a dynamic operation' error. If I change it to `IQueryable<object>` then my filtering in the `oneItem` doesn't work.

Comment: What is type of 'item.Property?

Comment: @JenishRabadiya in prod I have some 22 properties I select - Guid?, DateTime?, string, int?, double, Boolean?.

Answer (score 2):

You need to return

```
IQueryable<MyObject>
```

You can make your methods/classes dry by using genrics eg

```
IQuerable<T> GetQueryable()
```

Then the consumer can specify what T should be and your away.

You can't use dynamic with linq. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3588956/limitations-of-the-dynamic-type-in-c-sharp) to understand why.

Comment: I am selecting an anonymous type as you can see in my example. So there is no type I want returned.

Comment: Why does it have to be anonymous? What is the reason for this?

Comment: I have a few tens of complex queries I want exposed like this and they can change very rapidly. I don't want to have to create and maintain objects purely so I can reuse the query inside a class.

Comment: Do you retrieve the items from a DB are you using entity framework?

Comment: OK either way you can't use dynamic with linq it doesn't work. I've updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

For two methods to communicate they must understand the same type so you really want to project into a named type.

If you insist on using dynamic programming it can be done but you will need a lot of casting because dynamic is not a type but just a way of treating object:

```
IQueryable<MyModel> q = new List<MyModel>().AsQueryable(); // this is just an example, this is obviously not a list

      IQueryable<object> query = from item in q select (object)new { item.Property };

      var oneItem = query.FirstOrDefault(x => ((dynamic)x).SomeProperty == somevalue);
      object[] allItems = query.ToArray();
```

Comment: unfortunately I get 'An expression tree may not contain a dynamic operation' again on the cast to dynamic here: `var oneItem = query.FirstOrDefault(x => ((dynamic)x).SomeProperty == somevalue);`